# simple bash strings contains compression is not working

Tags: linux, string, bash, if-statement, comparison

I'm sure there's probably a syntax mistake but I have looked and that's the way others seems to write it ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299710/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-substring-of-another-in-bash))
Can anyone please tell me why the following is happening-

```
h="23538_"
if [[ "$h" == "23538_" ]]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi;
>> true
if [[ *"$h"* == "23538_" ]]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi;
>> false
```

Also tried:

```
h=23538
if [[ *"$h"* == "23538_" ]]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi;
 >> false

if [[ *$h* == "23538_" ]]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi;
>> false

if [[ *{$h}* == "23538_" ]]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi
>> false

h='_23538__'
if [[ *"$h"* == "23538_" ]]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi
```

In a few words - I am trying to find if $h is a sub-string of "23538_" string.

Hope someone could help me...:)

Comment: Glob pattern can only be used on right hand side variable.

Comment: do you mean like this `if [[ "23538_" == *"$h"* ]]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi` ...?

Comment: it is still not working...:/

Comment: `h=23538; if [[ "23538_" == *"$h"* ]]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi` prints `true` for me.

Comment: I'm sorry you are right it is working... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to swap the arguments

```
 if [[ "23538_"  == *"$h"* ]]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi;
   > true
```

Answer (score 1):

Patterns can only be used on the right hand side if the `==` or `!=` operator. See `man bash` under `[[ expression ]]`:

> When the `==` and `!=` operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the  rules  described
>   below  under *Pattern Matching*, as if the `extglob` shell option were enabled.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$ echo $h  # true subset
23538
$ if [[ "23538_" =~ "$h" ]]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi;
true
```

`man bash`:

> An  additional  binary  operator, =~, is available, with the same
>   precedence as == and !=.  When it is used, the string to the right of
>   the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex(3)).